# SAS execute macro conditionally

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I want to execute a macro conditionally, based on some loop variable in the dataset.

```
data alldat;
    do i=1 to 5;

        * here, a macro should be called ;
        * that is accessing some array variable of the dataset ;
        * e.g. %my_macro(my_array(i));

        %put hello; 
        output;
    end;
run;

proc print; run;
```

How is this possible?
If I execute this example code above, `hello` is only output once, while `alldat` contains 5 values, as one would expect. I want 5 `hello`s in my output.

Thank you!

Comment: It would probably help if you described the actual problem you want to solve with some sample input and output data.

Comment: This isn't directly answerable any more than Tom did. The complete answer would need to depend on what your macro was doing.  Please provide an example macro that does whatever you are trying to do here.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your data step loop to output `hello` 5 times then use a `PUT` statement instead of a `%PUT` statement.

In general macros are used to generate SAS code that is then executed. It really depends on what type of code your macro generates. If it only generates statements than can be used inside of a data step then call it once inside of your `DO` loop and the generated statements will run 5 times.  So if your macro generates data step statements that could update the variable whose name is passed to it then your code might look like this.

```
data alldata;
  array my_array var1-var5 ;
  do i=1 to dim(my_array);
    %my_macro(my_array(i)); 
    put 'hello';
    output;
  end;
run;
```

Otherwise you could use `CALL EXECUTE` to generate the macro calls so that they can then run and generate their code after the data step stops. This data step will read values from an existing array and pass the values to the macro.  So it will generate 5 calls to the macro for every observation in the input data. The generated macro calls will run after the data step stops.

```
data _null_;
  set mydata;
  array my_array var1-var5 ;
  do i=1 to dim(my_array);
    call execute(cats('%nrstr(%my_macro)(',my_array(i),');'));
    call execute('%nrstr(%put hello;)'); 
  end;
run;
```